# Facebook's Checkbox plugin remains hidden no matter what I try

Tags: facebook-graph-api, checkbox, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm having trouble getting the [Messenger Checkbox plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/checkbox-plugin/) to work: the Facebook script loads fine, it parses the page well (I can see this with the debug version of the SDK), but the checkbox remains in "hidden" status.

This is an HTML sample of my page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TestCheckboxMessenger</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
          appId: "[my-app-id]",
          autoLogAppEvents: true,
          xfbml: true,
          version: "v10.0",
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe("messenger_checkbox", function (e) {
          if (e.event == "rendered") {
            console.log("Plugin was rendered");
          } else if (e.event == "checkbox") {
            var checkboxState = e.state;
            console.log("Checkbox state: " + checkboxState);
          } else if (e.event == "not_you") {
            console.log("User clicked 'not you'");
          } else if (e.event == "hidden") {
            console.log("Plugin was hidden");
          }
        });
      };
    </script>
    <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk/debug.js"
    ></script>

    <div
      class="fb-messenger-checkbox"
      origin="https://[my-domain-name]/"
      page_id="[my-page-id]"
      messenger_app_id="[my-app-id]"
      user_ref="[some-random-id]"
      size="medium"
      skin="light"
      center_align="true"
    ></div>

    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have carefully read the facebook documentation and the solutions proposed on StackOverflow, but the checkbox does not appear. I have taken into account the following points:

- My page is served on HTTPS with a domain name that is whitelisted in my page options
- The user_ref is a randomly generated id that is new on every page refresh
- My app is in what was called "development mode" so I have Standard access to *pages_messaging* and I have admin role on the app (and I am connected to my account)
- My Messenger webhook is live and working

As strange as it may seem, the conversation plugin works fine.

[What conversation plugin looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mpfv.png)

Is there a method to debug the checkbox status? To know why it is hidden? Because I have no error message in the Chrome console and all this is very frustrating :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so, acccording to [this Facebook Update](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/europe-japan-updates), the checkbox plugin and some other features including optin mechanics, media messages, etc. have been deactivated in Europe and some other countries because of GDPR.

Facebook planned to restore them by Q1 2021, but now they are moving the timeline towards Q2 2021.

I don't understand why they don't put a warning message on the docs about these features... :(